# Pie chart size, labels, distances

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I've created a pretty nice pie chart but it is still not perfect.
My code is:

```
labels_occurancy = ['composition', 'process', 'pathology', 'other_meds', 
'disposal', 'animal', 'device', 'cultivation', 'food', 
'tests', 'compliance']
size_occurancy = [199, 179, 63, 128, 33, 8, 44, 24, 37, 31, 4]
explode = (0.008, 0.008, 0.008,0.008,0.008,0.008,0.008,0.008,0.008,0.008,0.008)
textprops = {"fontsize":15}
plt.pie(size_occurancy, labels=labels_occurancy, explode=explode,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', pctdistance = 0.8, textprops =textprops,
        radius = 0.5)
plt.title('Classification in %', fontdict = {'fontsize':20})
plt.show()
```

The problem of my chart is next. With original size the pie was huge, all over the screen. That's why I decided to use `radius`. But with that reduction my labels become not clear and less readable (even if to increase the size of labels). And the biggest problem is that with reduction of radius there is still a lot of space below and under the chart. Can smb give me any explanations or suggestions plz?

Comment: What if you first set the graph size to, say, 9 inches and the radius to 1? `plt.figure(figsize=(9,9)); plt.pie(...radius=1)`

Answer (score 1):

**I hope that the following code helps you out:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

recipe = ["composition",
          "process",
          "pathology",
          "other_meds",
          "disposal",
          "animal",
          "device",
          "cultivation",
          "food",
          "tests",
          "pathology"]


data = [199, 179, 63, 128, 33, 8, 44, 24, 37, 31, 4]



#When you change the width to 0.5 you get a donut chart

wedges, texts = ax.pie(data, wedgeprops=dict(width=1), startangle=-140)

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
kw = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
          bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(recipe[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(2*np.sign(x), 2*y),
                horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)

#ax.set_title("Title of graph")

plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can still add the according percentages and the title into the graph. But I still don't understand what you wanted to express with the explode 0.008.

Answer (score 0):

As it happens sometimes, after restarting the computer the graph has got completely other shape and after small corrections, I don't have any problems with spaces anymore. All other graphs were ok and they didn't change any shape.